# Collection Enumeration Searching for Strings in Order

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, collections, nspredicate

I have an array that contains 500 strings (`NSString`), each represents only one character (ex: `@"H"`) which I will loop through from start to end.

Among these strings there are for example strings such as `@"H"`, `@"e"`, `@"l"`, `@"l"`, `@"o"`.

They are ***definitely*** in the array but the order is unknown.

I would like to loop through the array from start to end and would like to print out
"Hello" with no repeats. Just once. And the string `@"H"` has to occur first before "ello".

So when the first `@"H"` occurs I would start to look for the rest namely "ello" and print them out.

Been thinking about this for the past hour and I could not come anything unfortunately except that:

Perhaps there are some condition such as `NSPredicate` etc where I could first find the index numbers of these strings in order before the loop takes place. And so I could just print them out without having to check as I loop through the array and thus making use of a bunch of `if-else`.

***For example:***

```
NSArray *indexesThatMatchTheStrings = [......(condition => @"H", @"e", @"l", @"l", @"o").....]'
```

And `indexesThatMatchTheStrings` would contain the matching indexes. If the condition isn't satisfied, then I would know beforehand I don't have to print them out. Again, "H", "e", "l", "l", "o" are there within the array, but the order matters.

Is there some operation like this in collections? I am open to any kind of collections and algorithms (i.e. `NSSet`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` etc). Even methods in `C` (bit shifts, structs, memory compare, etc). Some thing fast and light-weight.

***Addendum:***

To generalize a bit the use case:

Are there any ways or method provided by the framework with which we could set a test condition for a collection such as an array, a dictionary or a set, where we could find out whether some things are in fact within them based on a particular condition (in my case here: the h e l l o sequence), so that we could minimize the looping + comparing overhead? Or even avoid the need to loop + search altogether, since we know the search condition is not met for the collection?

Comment: Could you give an example of the exact output you are looking for from an example input?  I can think of a couple scenarios with your description and just want to get exactly what you want.

Comment: lets look at the problem abstractly, so we first find "H" then we iterate further to find "E" and then the rest of the string. Did I understand your question properly ?

Comment: @Putz1103 Thanks for response. There are characters within this array and "H", "e", "l", "l", "o" are definitely there (each character can have repeats in this array but the order is unknown). And I would like to check whether there exist continuous characters "H" "e" "l" "l" "o" within it by making use of some fast enumeration techniques / methods in collections.

Comment: @Basheer_CAD You understand me correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

And here is my version:

```
NSArray * allChars = @[@"l", @"A", @"B", @"H", @"b", @"e", @"H", @"c", @"c", @"l", @"b", @"q", @"l", @"l", @"l", @"z", @"o", @"H", @"e", @"l",@"l", @"o", @"l"];
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF in[cd] %@", @[@"H", @"e", @"l", @"o"]];
NSArray * equal = [allChars filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSString * sayHello = @"";

// This loop will find any sequence of Hello's characters

for (int i=0; i<equal.count; i++)
{
    NSString * nextChar = equal[i];
    NSString * try = [sayHello stringByAppendingString:nextChar];

    if ([@"Hello" rangeOfString:try].location == 0) {
        sayHello = try;
    }

    if ([sayHello rangeOfString:@"Hello"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Hello!");
        break;
    }
}

// This loop works if between Hello's char cannot be any other characters

sayHello = @"";

for (int i=0; i<equal.count; i++)
{
    sayHello = [sayHello stringByAppendingString:equal[i]];
    if ([sayHello rangeOfString:@"Hello"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Hello!");
        break;
    }
}

return YES;
```

**EDIT**: And thanks to [@melvas's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2087567/melvas) that wrote regular expression, i made the same with NSRegularExpression and with no loops:

```
    NSString * possibleHello = [equal componentsJoinedByString:@""];    
    NSString * regex = @"(?=(h|H))(.*?)(?=(e|E))(.*?)(?<=(l|L))(.*?)(?=(l|L))(.*?)(?=(o|O))";

    NSError * error = nil;        
    NSRegularExpression * regularExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regex
                                                                                 options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators
                                                                                   error:&error];
    NSArray * matches = [regularExp matchesInString:possibleHello
                                            options:NSMatchingReportProgress
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, posibleHello.length)];
    if (matches.count) {
        NSLog(@"Hello!");
    }
```

Comment: +1 for making use of predicate. Will give it a try, but I am curious to know also whether or not it is possible to check a condition (in my sample case: the hello string sequence, for example) within an array without looping and comparing with the use of some methods in objective-c collections.

Comment: I thought about this, but seem it impossible, because of double 'l'. When you will make `[NSSet  setWithArray: equal]` to remove duplicates you will also remove 'll'

Comment: And if there were only one 'l' it would be possible without using loop?

Comment: sure, `NSSet * set = [NSSet setWithArray:equal];
    NSString * posibleHello = [set.allObjects componentsJoinedByString:@""];` but `possibleHello` will contain reversed 'oleH' word, so you need compare it with reversed word)

Answer (score 1):

First pass answer of your problem given my interpretation of your problem (this is assuming you are looping through your array anyway):

You know what characters you are looking for and in what order you are looking for them (I'm assuming).  So create an array of the objects you want and the exact order you want.  Then loop through the data array and check each object against your known array and the current position in that array.  Then print, save, dow whatever with the information there.

```
NSArray *knownArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"H", @"e", @"l", @"l", @"o", nil];
int currentLocationInKnownArray = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < [data count]; i++)
{
    if([[data objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[knownArray objectAtIndex:currentLocationInKnownArray]])
    {
        //You found a match
        currentLocationInKnownArray++;

        //Do whatever else you would like with the index or data from this loop.
    }
}

//Now check if you found your complete set
if(currentLocationInKnownArray == [knownArray count])
{
    //You found them all in order in your array.
}
```

If you are not going to be iterating your array anyway, then you can use different functions inside NSArray (this may take quite a bit longer than a single loop because we iterate through the whole array multiple times, but Apple may have optimized these functions a bit):

```
NSArray *knownArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"H", @"e", @"l", @"l", @"o", nil];

__block int currentIndexInMaster = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < [knownArray count]; i++)
{
    __block bool validObjectFound = false;
    NSIndexSet *set = [data indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if([(NSString*)obj isEqualToString:[knownArray objectAtIndex:i]])
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }];

    [set enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        //... do something with idx
        // *stop = YES; to stop iteration early
        if(idx > currentIndexInMaster)
        {
            currentIndexInMaster = idx;
            validObjectFound = true;
            *stop = TRUE;
        }
    }];

    if(!validObjectFound)
    {
        //No longer valid data, do not continue
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks +1, I will give it a try. `enumerateUsingBlock` is not a stranger to me. In my case, yes, I will need to traverse the whole array anyway. But was also curious rather or not we could place a condition on a collection (such as an array) and know beforehand whether some thing is in fact within the array so that looping + comparing can be minimized or avoid altogether.